# KQL: deduplication, record priority and sorting

Tags: sorting, duplicates, kql, azure-data-explorer, summarize

I'm new to Kusto and trying to figure out how to de-dupe in KQL. I have a table in Kusto that stores account information. For some of the accounts, the table has 2 rows: one with updated_c == true and another row with updated_c == false. I would like to write a KQL script that would survive the row with updated_c == true in these cases of duplicate accounts. In other words, I'm trying to de-dupe this dataset where when there are 2 rows per each account, it would survive the one with updated_c == true. And if there are only one row per perspective account, it would survive it regardless of updated_c vlaues.

| account Id | updated_c |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | true |
| 12 | false |

would anyone be able to help me learn how to de-dupe this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
datatable
| extend updated_c_int = toint(updated_c)
| summarize arg_max(updated_c_int, *) by accountId
| project accountId, updated_c
```

- `extend updated_c_int = toint(updated_c)`: Convert the boolean `updated_c` to an integer. `true` becomes 1 and `false` becomes 0.
- `summarize arg_max(updated_c_int, *) by accountId`: For each `accountId`, get the row with the highest value of `updated_c_int`. If there's a tie, `arg_max` will return the first row it encounters.
- `project accountId, updated_c`: Only select the columns `accountId` and `updated_c` in the final output.

Given your example input, this query should return:

```
accountId    updated_c
12           true
```